# orderyBy with ng-repeat not working

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I am trying to order by the likes of an answer. I looked at the angular documentation for orderBy and it looks like I am following it.  However, my table is not ordering by the likes for answer.  Here is my html.  If you want me to post more code let me know.

```
<div ng-controller="answerAndQuestionController"> 
    <h1 ng-bind='question.question'></h1>
    <h1 ng-bind='question.description'></h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Answer</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Likes</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat = "answer in answers | orderBy:'answer.likes'">
                <td><input ng-model = "answer.answer" readonly></td>
                <td><input ng-model = "answer.description" readonly></td>
                <td><input ng-model = "answer.user" readonly></td>
                <td><input ng-model = "answer.likes" readonly>
                    <button ng-click = "like(answer.answer)" href="">like</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Try without `answer`, like this `<tr ng-repeat = "answer in answers | orderBy:'likes'">`

Comment: Thanks, post it so I can give you credit for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check Angular's [orderBy example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy#example) you'll notice the analogy to define expression in `orderBy` without "object" (`answer`)

`<tr ng-repeat = "answer in answers | orderBy:'likes'">`

Comment: The idea behind the filtering is that you already have ```answer``` and now you are going to *pipe* those variables into the filter which in this case is the orderBy filter